# Does a static $\vec E$-field Increase the gauge invariant vector potential without bound?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, maxwell-equations, gauge-invariance

[The gauge invariant formulation of Maxwell's Laws (7.13)](http://www.ece.unm.edu/summa/notes/Physics/0006.pdf):

[image]

Indicates that the transverse electric field is the time derivative of the transverse vector potential.

This gauge invariant vector potential increases without bound as long as there exists a static electric field.  Indeed, even when the electric field is removed, there appears to be no mechanism by which the gauge invariant vector potential disappears.

In what way am I misinterpreting (7.13)?

Comment: A transverse electric field requires a changing current, so I think we need not worry about unbounded growth in the vector potential, because that requires an unbounded increase in current density.

Answer (score 1):

> This gauge invariant vector potential increases without bound as long as there exists a static electric field. Indeed, even when the electric field is removed, there appears to be no mechanism by which the gauge invariant vector potential disappears.

Static electric field has zero transversal component; entire field is longitudinal.

The unbounded increase of vector potential would occur if you used the gauge where the static electric field is given as time derivative of vector potential.

Answer (score 1):

A static E field, results either from a charge distribution giving potential $V$, or from a current density $j \propto t$ giving a vector potential $A \propto t$.

For an infinite current sheet, say in the xy plane, one has $A \propto |z|$, just like $V \propto |z|$ for an infinite charge sheet.
If $j \propto t$, a static E field and $A \propto |z|t $ result.

Obviously the sheet is finite and also the linear time dependency and $A \propto |z|t $ can only hold close to the sheet and for a limited time interval.

This type of problem is more readily understood in terms of the potentials. E and B lose their meanings for time dependent charge and/or current distributions, as should be clear from the Maxwell-Faraday equation and Ampère's law. However, physicists are conservative and keep using the pre 20th century E and B. On the other hand, the meaning of V as potential energy and $\vec A$ as potential momentum are quite clear.